# ajax is not working with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax code.

I cannot see any error in my code, but AJAX doesn't work.

It doesn't return anything from that page...

```
function addCash(){ 
 var cash =$('#cash_amount').val();
 var date =$('#cash_date').val(); 
 var debiter =$('#debiter').val();  
 if(cash == '' || date =='' ){
 alert("Please Fill All Fields");
 }
else{
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    url: 'getCustomers.php',
    data: 'type=cash_received&cash='+cash+'&date='+date+'& debiter='+debiter,
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert("Cash Added Successfully");
    }
});
}
}
```

PHP Code "getCustomers.php"...inside a function using ajax is an issue?

```
$cash= $_REQUEST['cash'];
$date= $_REQUEST['date'];
$debiter= $_REQUEST['debiter'];
$query="INSERT INTO `received_payment`(`debiter`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES ('".$debiter."', '".$cash."', '".$date."')";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or ($error=$mysqli->error.LINE);

$arr = array();
if(!$result){
$arr['result'] = isset($error) ? $error : 'error';
}
else{
$arr['result'] ="ok";
}
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
ob_clean();
echo $json_response;`
```

Comment: Are you having these codes in the same page?

Comment: no..some uploading issues..so i put it here together..sorry for that

Comment: what do you get in the Network tab of browser. Any console Error?

Comment: no...it doesn't return anything

Comment: But i put it inside a function..its not an issue right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are using `die` anf if your query fails then your script will die and hence no response will be made. So change the below line,

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

to

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or ($error=$mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

and you can return this error in response like,

```
if(!$result){
   $arr['result'] = isset($error) ? $error : 'error';
}
```

Also in your insert query, fields and their values are not matching, you should use it like,

```
$query="INSERT INTO `received_payment` (`debiter`, `amount`, `date`) 
                       VALUES ('".$debiter."', ".$cash."', '".$date."')";
```

And try to pass data from AJAX (you have space before debiter key in your data string) like,

```
data: {type:'cash_received',cash:cash,date:date,debiter:debiter},
```

Comment: Pass `data` like `data: {type:'cash_received',cash:cash,date:date,debiter:debiter},` , see my updated answer.

Comment: See your browser's console, if it has any errors. And make sure that your Ajax call request is made.

Comment: after using the error funtion i got error  `  error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    } `..but it also doesn't return which error..simply returns 'error' only

Answer (score 0):

An extra comma in INSERT query.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `received_payment`(`debiter`, `amount`, `date`,) VALUES ('".$cash."', '".$date."', '".$debiter."')";
```

Change to:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `received_payment`(`debiter`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES ('".$cash."', '".$date."', '".$debiter."')";
```

It is giving an `error` actually, but since you gave `die()` the code is getting exited. So you are not getting anything from Server.

Answer (score 0):

in AJAX request you have mentioned accept only JSON data content. So in some case it may happens server returns response with Warning and Error if PHP error is on.

So in server side PHP script before echo response in json format you can use `ob_clean()` for flushing all unexpected output which is sent by error or warning.

```
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
ob_clean();
echo $json_response;
```

Comment: Now i have updated my code..just check it out..it still return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Please  remove  quotes at the end of the  line

```
echo $json_response;`
```